# Формат чисел java

Tags: java, spring, frontend, thymeleaf

Spring + thymeleaf.
Мне нужно чтобы было два знака после запятой. (Вот так: 0.00)

В модели метод делает вот так:

> double balanceStart = 0.0d;

```
public double getBalanceStart() {
    String formattedDouble = String.format("%.2f", balanceStart);
    return Double.parseDouble(formattedDouble.replace(',', '.'));
}
```

Если вывести в консоль formattedDouble и Double.parseDouble(formattedDouble.replace(',', '.') то будет: 0.00

Но когда фронт вызывает метод и получает это значение, он рисует на страничке: 0.0

> ```
> <div class="col" th:each="report : ${reports}" th:text="${report.getBalanceStart()}"></div>
> ```

Что же я делаю не так?

Comment: Так фронт у Вас получает число, а не сторку. И выводит так, как сам считает нужным. Форматируйте вывод на фронте.

Comment: @Adm123 понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для форматирования чисел Thymeleaf имеет целый набор утилит [Expression Utility Objects](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#appendix-b-expression-utility-objects). То что вам надо это [Numbers](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers) объект. По названию функции, я так понимаю, вы работаете с деньгами и для этого можно воспользоваться форматированием для денег ...

```
<span th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(report.balance)}">$10.23</span>
```

Этот метод прост, но будет печатать доллар символ перед значением. Если вас это не устраивает , то можно просто отформатировать ваше значение испольуя `#numbers.formatDecimal` функцию ...

```
<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(report.balance, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}">10.00</span> руб.
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо!